# Yii 2 starter kit docker - composer create project - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set .. when following the docs

Tags: docker, yii2

The question is, when creating a Yii 2 starter kit project by a composer create-project command in Docker in spite of when following the documentation very exactly

https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/installation.md#get-source-code-via-composer

```
composer create-project yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit myproject.com
```

it results in an error

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for league/uri 5.3.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri[5.3.0].
    - league/uri 5.3.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for league/uri-components 1.8.2 -> satisfiable by league/uri-components[1.8.2].
    - league/uri-components 1.8.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for league/uri-hostname-parser 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by league/uri-hostname-parser[1.1.1].
    - league/uri-hostname-parser 1.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for league/uri-manipulations 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri-manipulations[1.5.0].
    - league/uri-manipulations 1.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - league/uri 5.3.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - trntv/yii2-glide 1.2.2 requires league/uri ^5.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri[5.3.0].
    - Installation request for trntv/yii2-glide 1.2.2 -> satisfiable by trntv/yii2-glide[1.2.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the composer create-project command is listed as one of the available options for creating the project

https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/installation.md#get-source-code-via-composer

, however, the better way when using it inside a docker not to need having all the dependencies at the host system is to retrieve the files via git

`git clone https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit.git`

removing the .git folder for the project's git log, or ignoring the initial errors

afterward installing the project dependencies using the following command which internally utilizes internal docker composer command/environment

```
composer run-script docker:build
```

as that environment is specially pre-prepared to contain all such dependent libraries and prevents such errors altogether